# How to get rows and colums in sql?

Tags: android, sql

in my app i have a database and i want to get specific rows sorting by tags names to my cursor and show it in a CursorAdapter , i want to return the rows by "name1" of tags i put.
I'm bad at explaining so here's a picture

[image]

and my code:

```
public Cursor getCursor(String theTags) {
    open();
    Cursor cursor = myDb.query(TABLE_DAY, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    close();
    return cursor;
}
```

CursorAdapter:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

TextView data1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_data1);
data1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHandler.DATA1)));
TextView data2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_data2);
data1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHandler.DATA2)));

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the row sorted by column TAG?

Answer (score 0):

When you query the database, try this.

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.query(TABLE_DAY, null, "TAG=?", new String[]{"name1"}, null, null, "TAG ASC", null)
```

I have edited the answer to suit your need.

Comment: Sorry but I did not explain myself correctly. i want the all rows with the tags of "name1" . only the gray parts. (A,B,C)

Comment: This edited answer will give you all of the rows with tags of name1.

Comment: 08-21 04:20:18.656: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.